# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module path not found

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, compiler-errors, java-11

```
package start;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Crawler extends Application {

public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    BorderPane borderPane =  new BorderPane() ;
    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane) ;`` 
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setWidth(600);
    stage.setHeight(400);
    stage.show();


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

I wrote this code so I can try JavaFX for the first time but when I was trying to launch the program 
I got this error:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module path not found

I have a project called crawler 
another class called crawler and I added the java fx library to my project

can anyone give me a solution to how I can solve this and thanks

Comment: and i added this to my argument run file configuration tab 
--module path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib"
 --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

Comment: Did you check https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse ?

Comment: `--module<space>path`, looks like you are missing a dash.

Comment: alan bateman what do you mean i am missing a dash ?

Comment: u am using javafx 11 because i am using java 11

Comment: i  needed to add the dash --module-path